# SSIS package not running from SQL server catalog

Tags: ssis

I have created one project for SSIS and deployed that on sql server 2014. When I am running packages from sql server data tool its running fine and performing all operations, but when I am running from catlog procs [SSISDB].[CATALOG].[Create_execution] its shows run successful but I can't see any data into my staging tables. I have used configuration tables to configure connection and files path.
Any idea.

Comment: Do you have any parameters in your package?

Comment: Yes and I am sending same parameter as sending from data tools

Comment: I faced a similar problem some time ago and the reason was the order of the parameters - this resulted in the package not finding any records. Another possibility might be user privileges: are you executing the procedures with the same user you use in Data Tools?

Comment: Ok so problem was shared folder which was accessible from visual studio but not from sql server. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer.

Comment: You should have seen some error messages in the SSIS reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLease check the user privileges (file system, etc.) - if you call the procedures with another user than you execute the package from within Data Tools, this might be the reason.